# @media query working in a strange way

Tags: javascript, html, css

Over the Christmas period, I paused working on my website. I came back to it this week, to find that the code had been changed, somehow. I've included all the code, but the main parts I want to address are the `.fadein` css, particularly, the snippet below.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1110px) {
.fadein img {
    width:auto;
    height:72.1%;
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -0%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -0%);
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

Something in this code is causing my slideshow/images to show up as tiny thumbnail size images, instead of the full-screen size they were meant to be. On removing the width and/or height properties, the image goes larger than I like, but I can't scale it. Any ideas? The rest of the code is below, if required. Thanks!

```js
$(function() {

    $('.fadein img:gt(0)').hide();
    
    setInterval(function() {
    
     $('.fadein :first-child').fadeOut(2000)
      
         .next('img').fadeIn(2000)
         
         .end().appendTo('.fadein');
         
     }, 5000);
});
```

```css
html {
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 height:100%;
 width:100%;
 position:relative;
}

body {
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 height:100%;
 width:100%;
 position:absolute;
 bottom:0;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 right:0;
}

p {
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 color:#1C1C1C;
}

img {
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}

.maincontainer {
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 position:relative;
}

.container {
 width:100%;
 min-height:100%;
 position:relative;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}

.container:after {
 content:"";
 display:block;
}

.logo {
 float:left;
 margin-left:30px;
 font-family:'Advent Pro', sans-serif;
 font-weight:100;
 font-size:40px;
 color:#1C1C1C;
}

.photography {
 width:100px;
 float:left;
 margin-top:7px;
 margin-left:10px;
 padding-left:10px;
 font-family:'Advent Pro', sans-serif;
 font-weight:100;
 font-size:16px;
 color:#1C1C1C;
 border-left:1px solid #1C1C1C;
}

@media screen and (min-width:768px) {
 .logo {
  float:left;
  margin-left:15px;
  font-family:'Advent Pro', sans-serif;
  font-weight:100;
  color:#1C1C1C;
 }
}

.name {
 float:left;
 margin:5px 10px 0px 10px;
 font-size:37px;
}

.type {
 float:left;
 width:50px;
 margin-top:6px;
 padding:1px 0px 1px 10px;
 font-size:15px;
 border-left:1px solid #1C1C1C;
}

.nav {
 float:right;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 list-style:none;
 width:300px;
}

@media screen and (min-width:500px) {
 .nav {
  float:right;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  list-style:none;
  width:444px;
 }
}

.nav li {
 float:left;
 padding:16px 10px 13px 10px;
 font-family:'Advent Pro', sans-serif;
 font-weight:200;
 font-size:17px;
 color:#1C1C1C;
}

.nav li:hover {
 border-bottom:2px solid #1C1C1C;
}


@media screen and (min-width:500px) {
 .nav li {
  float:left;
  padding:16px 25px 13px 25px;
  font-family:'Advent Pro', sans-serif;
  font-weight:200;
  font-size:17px;
  color:#1C1C1C;
 }
}

.reposition {
 position:absolute;
 left:50%;
 -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -0%);
 -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -0%);
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
 .reposition {
  position:static;
  float:right;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-0%, -0%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-0%, -0%);
 }
}

.navbar-toggle {
 margin-top:13px;
 position:absolute;
 right:0;
}

.collapse {
 height:56px;
 width:100%;
}

.navbar-header {
 float:left;
 display:inline-block;
 height:55px;
 padding:0;
 margin:0;
}

.mainbody {
 width:100%;
 padding:0 0 20px 0;
 margin:0;
 float:left;
}

.slideshow {
 width:100%;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}

.fadein {
 width:100%;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}

.fadein img {
 width:93.8%;
 height:auto;
 position:absolute;
 left:50%;
 -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -0%);
 -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -0%);
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1110px) {
 .fadein img {
  width:auto;
  height:72.1%;
  position:absolute;
  left:50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -0%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -0%);
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
 }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1441px) {
 .fadein img {
  width:72.3%;
  height:auto;
  position:absolute;
  left:50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -0%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -0%);
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
 }
}

.mainfooter {
 width:100%;
 height:20px;
 position:absolute;
 bottom:0;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 float:left;
 position:fixed;
}

.footer {
 position:relative;
 bottom:1px;
 float:right;
 width:100%;
 height:20px;
 padding:0 10px 0 0;
 background-color:#F8F8F8;
 border:1px solid #E7E7E7;
 margin:0;
}

.copyright {
 float:right;
 font-family: 'Advent Pro', sans-serif;
 font-weight: 100;
 font-size:12px;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1441px) {
 .copyright {
  float:right;
  font-family: 'Advent Pro', sans-serif;
  font-weight:200;
  font-size:12px;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
 }
}

.media li {
 float:left;
 list-style:none;
 position:relative;
 left:10px;
 bottom:2px;
 margin:0 3px 0 3px;
 padding:0;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:480px) {
 .media li {
  display:none;
 }
}

.media {
 padding:0;
 margin:0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

 <head>
 
     <title>Tim Corin Wildlife Photography</title>
    
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <meta name="description" content="Award-winning wildlife, landscape, and event photographer based in Julatten, North Queensland, Australia.">
     <meta name="keywords" content="wildlife, bird, animal, photo, photography, photographer, camera, julatten, queensland, australia, events, landscape, affordable, cairns, port douglas, mossman">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
     
     <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poiret+One|Josefin+Slab|Cinzel|Jura:400,300|Nixie+One|Advent+Pro:100,300,200' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
     <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
     <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
     
     <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  
 </head>
   
 <body>
  
 <div class="maincontainer">
 
 <div class="mainheader">
 
   <div class="navbar navbar-default">
   
    <div class="container">
       
        <div class="navbar-header">
        
     <a href="index.html">
     
      <p class="logo">Tim Corin</p>
      <p class="photography">Wildlife Photography</p>
      
     </a>
      
         <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
         
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          
         </button>
         
        </div>
        
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
       
         <div class="reposition">
         
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
         
           <a href=""><li class="home">Home</li></a>
       <a href=""><li class="gallery">Gallery</li></a>
       <a href=""><li>About</li></a>
       <a href=""><li>Contact</li></a>
       <a href=""><li>Blog</li></a>
      
          </ul>
         
         </div>
         
        </div>
        
       </div>
       
   </div>
  
  </div>
  
  <div class="mainbody">
   
  <div class="slideshow">
   
   <div class="fadein">
    
    <img src="images/frog.jpg" />
    <img src="images/sunrays.jpg" />
    <img src="images/beeeater.jpg" />
    <img src="images/sunrise.jpg" />
    <img src="images/darter.jpg" />
    <img src="images/milkyway.jpg" />
   
   </div>
   
  </div>
  
 </div>
 
 <div class="mainfooter">
 
  <div class="footer">
 
   <div class="social">
        
        <ul class="media">
       
         <p class="copyright">Copyright Tim Corin Photography 2016. All Rights Reserved.</p>
        
         <a href="http://www.facebook.com/timcorinphotography" target="_blank"><li class="facebook"><img src="images/facebook.png" height="16px"/></li></a>
         <a href="http://www.instagram.com/timcorinphotography" target="_blank"><li class="instagram"><img src="images/instagram.png" height="16px"/></li></a>
     <a href="http://www.twitter.com/timcorinphoto" target="_blank"><li class="twitter"><img src="images/twitter.png" height="16px"/></li></a>
        
        </ul>
        
       </div>
       
   </div>
      
 </div>
 
 </div>
 
   </body>
   
</html>
```

Comment: It could be the fact you're not closing the `@media` query. However, if you need help you should create a [mcve] of your problem. As in... **Minimal**? **Verifiable**? (out of curiosity, press the **Run code snippet** button - see what happens)...

Answer (score 0):

I think that you're not closing the media query.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1110px) {
    .fadein img {
        width:auto;
        height:72.1%;
        position:absolute;
        left:50%;
        -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -0%);
        -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -0%);
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
    }
    }
```